# Generate random but always different numbers within a range with CSPRNG

Tags: algorithm, random, hash, cryptography, random-seed

I have a CSPRNG that I'm using to generate 5 numbers between 0 and 20. The problem is, there could be cases where it generates the same number again. So say it generates 5 but running again, it could come out to be 5. If not, then the third or 4th number could be 5.

I want a way to do this where I'm 100% sure the 5 numbers are never the same, even if they do come up as same, I want to re-generate that number in a way that none of the numbers clash.

I thought of using a while loop for each number, to regenerate the number while it's same as the other 4 numbers but that obviously is not optimal and may cause to get stuck in long loops.

Is there a better way?

Comment: how about filling the range with the numbers and then shuffle?

Answer (score 2):

so as far as I understand that question you want a way to find N unique random numbers from your CSPRNG within the specified range and an execution time that's independant from the numbers generated from the underlying CSPRNG

```
make an array with your number range (here 0 to 20 => 21 elements)
run a loop for all array elements:
let idx = array index of current element
let jdx = CSPRNG(within range -1; here between 0 and 19 inclusive)
if jdx >= idx add 1 to jdx // idx and jdx are now 2 distinct array index positions
swap array elements idx and jdx
```

your N uniqe random numbers are the N first/last elements of the array